# Twitter4J sendDirectMessage returns page does not exist

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

I want to develop an application who can send direct messages look this:

```
public static void sendDirectMessage(Long recipientId, String message){
    System.out.print("[Bot] Sending message to @"+recipientId+"...  ");
    try {
        twitter.sendDirectMessage(recipientId, message);
        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        System.out.println("fail");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("[Error] "+e.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

I call to this statement with:

```
private static String
        customer_key = "",
        Oth_key = "",
        access_token = "",
        access_key = "";

private static TwitterBot bot;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        bot = new TwitterBot(customer_key, Oth_key, access_token, access_key);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("[Err] "+e.getMessage());
    }
    bot.sendDirectMessage(bot.getUserData("AbA2L1").getId(), "Message test:!");
}
```

it's return error:

```
404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
message - Sorry, that page does not exist.
code - 34
```

Note:

The functions search(), getHomeTimeline() and updateStatus() works.

I have activated Read, Write and Direct messages on twitter application permissions.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Twitter4J are you using? The new Direct Message API is only a few weeks old so you may need a new version.

Comment: I'm using `org.twitter4j:twitter4j-code:4.0.3` I'm going to try the last stable relase who are `4.0.7`

Comment: the core-4.0.7 doesn't reconize ConfigurationBuilder class! Where can I download it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's work with this vertion, add it into `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter4j-core-4.0.7 version for Direct Message Functionality of Twitter.
Other Version of Twitter4j Library shows TwitterException of User Not Found or Page Does not exist.